# How do thumbs up in comments work?

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I don't even know what questions I should ask. Well, I want to create a thumbs up for my comments, but not sure how or what's the best way. Do I just create a new field for thumbs up?

Comment: Tip: when asking a question, provide some context. For instance, when you say "your comments," do you mean that you're storing comments for a forum or somesuch in a database, and want to add some sort of thumbs up field? Taking a few extra seconds to phrase your question in an intelligent, thoughtful manner will tend to make others give your question more consideration. If you can't be bothered to write a good question, we probably won't take the time to write a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to keep track of who's voted on what, you should perhaps make a `Votes` table:

- `vote_id`: Primary key.
- `user_id`: The id of the user who made this vote. [Foreign key to `Users` table.]
- `comment_id`: The id of the comment that was voted on. [Foreign key to `Comments` table.]
- `vote`: The vote that was cast (perhaps +1 or -1 if you only have a trivial thumbs up/down system).
- `date`: When the vote was cast.

A comment's score is now just the sum of all the `vote` columns which have that `comment_id`.

Note that unlike simply adding an integer `score` column to your `Comments` table, this has the advantage of telling you the level of controversy a comment is experiencing. Without knowing how many votes were cast, two comments with a net score of zero could either be experiencing a lot of controversy (people are equally split about the merit of the comment, so the total score hovers around 0), or none at all (nobody cares enough to cast a vote).

Comment: vote_id is actually unnecessary, unless a user can place more than one vote on the same comment.

Comment: @Can: I presume it would be possible to do things like retract your vote once it's cast, and only the last one counts.

Comment: If you use MySQL (and possibly other DBs), it will create unique id column for you anyway if you don't create one.

Comment: @John, Can: No, I think it is more a question of database design. While in current situation vote_id is (technically!) unneccessary, it seems a good idea to me to use a separate identity column for the pk and declare a key on user_id and comment_id (to make them "unique together"). It is simply more flexible that way and costs you (almost) nothing.

Comment: @Peter: Really? That, certainly, is news to me. Does mysql *really* do that, or is it just a GUI of some sort you are using (mysql query browser?) making it for you?

Comment: This was an amazing answer! Thanks for explaining everything I need. :D

Comment: @shylent: I was too quick, and not very specific. This is not MySQL feature, but InnoDb engine feature: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Answer (score 4):

Just storing an int for the number of times a comment has been voted up would be subject to abuse.  You probably also want to associate each vote with the user who cast it, that way you can prevent people from repeatedly voting for the same comment.

For this to work, I think you'll need a separate table for votes.  Each record in that table should have the comment id and the user id of the person who cast the vote.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with this.  Why not just put an `int` column on your comments table, storing the total number of thumbs up / down for the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate table, as Bill and John have suggested, would probably be the best approach. But you might still want to add a `votes` column to the `comments` table for performance reasons. This way, you won't need to access the `votes` table when you only want to display the vote count for a comment. I believe this is how votes work on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 fields in your comment table, `vote_up` and `vote_down`, and increase their counters accordingly upon user's vote, this way you can display comment score as sum of these values or as a percentage, in the later case you could add third field `vote_score` which stores percentage score if you ever wanted to be able to sort by score.

Then create votes table to prevent users voting twice the same comment, ever or in given time span, if so just set cron job to run once a day and delete entries older than `time()-( 86400 * DAYS_TO_KEEP_VOTE )`

- comment_id
- user_id
- vote_time

Good luck.